# PyRal Rally Specific queries work but generic queries not returning data

Tags: rally, pyral

When I use the PyRal `get()` function no results are returned, but if I use specific built-in get functions (e.g., `getProjects()`, `getWorkspaces()`) all data is returned correctly. Am I using the general `get()` incorrectly or do I have a configuration issue?

For the setup:

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset
server, user, password, apikey, workspace, project = <appropriate values>
rally = Rally(server, user, password, apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)
```

These calls respond correctly (i.e., expected data returned):

```
workspacesAll = rally.getWorkspaces()
projectsAll = rally.getProjects(workspace=workspace)
```

No data returned for this call, no errors. The User Story exists in Rally.

```
query_criteria = 'FormattedID = "US220220"'
response = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement', fetch=True, query=query_criteria)
```

Have also tried using `"UserStory"` instead of `"HierarchicalRequirement"` and other query criteria all without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you go thru all Projects (not parent):

```
query_criteria = 'FormattedID = "US220220"'
response_req = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement', fetch=True, projectScopeDown=True, query=query_criteria)
response = response_req.next()

print response.details()
```

Comment: I'm getting data. Thank you very much.